# VSCODE API local file TypeError: Cannot read property 'extensionPath' of undefined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webview

I'm trying to make a VS Code extension with webview. I want to import stylesheet form other directory(`/CSS/index.css`).

Here is the structure of my program.

```
markmap-vscode
├─.vscode
├─CSS
│ ├─ index.css
│ └─ mindmap.css
├─examples
├─node_modules
├─src
│ └─ extension.js
...
```

Here is the part of `extenstion.js`, when I run this command(`markmap-vscode.startWebview`), it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'extensionPath`. But other VS Code API works well, and I read that `vscode.ExtensionContext.extensionPath` give path of extensions, but in this code, VS Code cannot find property of [`ExtensionContext`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext).

```js
  const startWebview = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    'markmap-vscode.startWebview',
    () => {
      const nowEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

      const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        'markMap',
        'makrdown to mind map',
        vscode.ViewColumn.Two,
        {
          enableScripts: true,
        },
      );
      // Get path to resource on disk
      try {
        const onDiskPathOfIndex = vscode.Uri.file(
          path.join(vscode.ExtensionContext.extensionPath, 'CSS', 'index.css'),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }

      panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();

    },
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(startWebview);
```

It makes a webview well, but it can't load local files. What is the difference between APIs why it can't find `extensionPath`?

Comment: I found a similar problem, related with security policy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233387/why-is-js-css-not-loaded-in-my-vsc-extension-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the doc link you provide:

> An instance of an ExtensionContext is provided as the **first parameter to the activate-call of an extension**.

Comment: Does it mean `context` in `function activate(context)` is the `ExtensionContext` of the extension I made?

Comment: @HyeonseoKim Yes

Comment: @rivoV8 Thank you for kind answer. I think I nead to improve my reading skills in english.